# What is the difference between the following 2 solutions of the leetcode puzzle Pow(x,n)

Tags: java, return-value, pow

I am working on the LeetCode question No.50 named Pow(x,n)(https://leetcode.com/problems/powx-n/). It asked me to return the n power of x. Below is my initial divide and conquer solution.

```
    public class Solution {
public double myPow(double x, int n) {
    if(n == 1) {return x;}
    if(n == 0) {return 1;}
    if(x == 0) {return 0;}
    if(x == 1) {return 1;}


    if(n>0)
    {
        if(n%2 == 1)
        {
            return (myPow(x,n/2)*myPow(x,n/2)*x);
        }
        else
        {
            return (myPow(x,n/2)*myPow(x,n/2));
        }
    }
    else if((n<0)&&(n>Integer.MIN_VALUE))
    {
        return (1/myPow(x,-n));
    }
    else return (1/(x*myPow(x,-n-1)));


  }
}
```

The problem is that for a very large n, this solution has a Time Limit Exceeded problem. However, if I change the code to the following, the Time Limit Exceeded problem is solved:

```
public class Solution {
public double myPow(double x, int n) {
    if(n == 1) {return x;}
    if(n == 0) {return 1;}
    if(x == 0) {return 0;}
    if(x == 1) {return 1;}


    if(n>0)
    {
        if(n%2 == 1)
        {
            double sub = myPow(x,n/2);
            return sub*sub*x;
        }
        else
        {
            double sub = myPow(x,n/2);
            return sub*sub;            }
    }
    else if((n<0)&&(n>Integer.MIN_VALUE))
    {
        return (1/myPow(x,-n));
    }
    else return (1/(x*myPow(x,-n-1)));


}
}
```

Why assigning the value of the sub-result could solve the Time Limit Exceeded problem? What makes the difference?

Comment: Method results aren't cached, so of course storing the value is preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because JVM don't know your two myPow(x,n/2) will do exactly the same thing, so it will calculate it twice. Assigning it to a local variable remove this penality, so your execution time is roughly <del>halfed</del>reduced to 1/2^n time. No more timeout then.